# Yii Toolbar triggering mixed content warning in CP

Tags: control-panel, debugging

I've enabled `Show the debug toolbar on the Control Panel` in my Craft Admin account in a local development environment that uses SSL. As soon as I enable it, I get the following error each time I load any page in the CP:

```
VM1685:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.dev/admin/myaccount' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://craft3.dev/actions/debug/default/toolbar?tag=5a495cbcf3e15'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

SSL seems to be set up and working fine. I have the `siteUrl` variable in my `general.php` set up with an `https` url as well:

```
'siteUrl' => 'https://domain.dev',
```

What could be triggering this warning?

Comment: Just tested locally and not able to reproduce.  Do you have a multi-site setup by chance?

Comment: Yes, I have several Sites. And, it looks like that's the issue. Updating the siteUrl setting fixes the error. Do you folks have any docs yet on what can be overridden in the `general.php` file? It looks like Sites stores the URL in the database.

Answer (score 1):

On a multi-site setup, you need to use the multi-site array syntax for the `siteUrl` config setting like so:

```
'siteUrl' => [
    'siteHandle1' => 'https://foo.com/',
    'siteHandle2' => 'https://bar.com/',
],
```

Comment: In my testing it appears that the `siteUrl` array in `general.php` does not override the `Sites->Base URL` setting that is stored in the db. If I set an array of `siteUrl`s in my general.php and then set incorrect values as my Base URLs in the Sites settings, the incorrect values continue to throw errors. Maybe the siteUrl setting gets respected in other places but it appears that the Debug Toolbar in the CP prioritizes the Base URL values in the db.